# PHP - Array for displaying errors

Tags: php, arrays, error-handling

How does/can an array be used to display errors in PHP:

```
$this->errors = array();
if($mysqli->errno){
    $this->errors[] = "There was an error ( {$mysqli->errno} ): {$mysqli->error}";
}
```

Is there some special code added before it or after it to display an error, or is it built into PHP to display an error with an array?

(I want to use it for my own framework)

Comment: Are You looking for a way to handle errors Yourself? You may be interested in error handling functions - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: I believe that are some special errors he is throwing and identifies them by some kind of id. Still, i don't know what exactly you wish to do.

Comment: The array is just repository for multiple error messages. Displaying it is up to later code. Even just a simple `foreach() {echo}` loop would do.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `class` that handles what error means what inside your framework and use other classes to process the error.

For example, if you want to show warning at your HTML for each error that happened in a form, you would use your *basic error class* and an *helper class* related to the *view*.

If you want to log your errors, you can use your *basic error class* and an *helper class* related to the *model*.

Good luck! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [error_get_last](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) function:

```
 $error = error_get_last();
if($error){
        $errorType = $error["type"];
        $errFile = $error["file"];
        $errLine = $error["line"];
        $errMessage  = $error["message"];

   $this->errors[] = $error["message"]; //but here you can set as you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure if that's what you're after but to display them you would go something like:

```
foreach($this->errors as $error)
{
    echo $error.'<br/>';
}
```